# Bluetooth connectivity issue

Tags: macos, bluetooth, gamepad

I apologise if this question is way out of the scope of this site. I am asking on here because I think this forum is the most likely place to get an good answer.

I bought a (fake) PS3 controller to use with my mac. When I try to connect the controller to my Mac, the Mac thinks the device is a keyboard and so requests a pincode to be entered on the keyboard - this is not possible on a gamepad.

Is there a bluetooth connections file on my Mac that can be edited to spoof the pin or a previous connection to the device?

Thanks.